# Monitor Cronjob running on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cron, cloud, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor a CronJob running on GKE and I cannot see an easy way of checking if the CronJob is actually running. I want to trigger an alert if the CronJob is not running for more than a X amount of time and Stackdriver does not seem to support that.

At the moment I tried using alerts based on logging metrics but that only serves me to alert in case of an app crash or specific errors not for the platform errors themselves.

I investigated a solution using Prometheus alerts, can that be integrated into Stackdriver?

UPDATE:
Just a follow up, ended up developing a simple solution using log based alerts on Stackdriver. If the log doesn't appear after X time then it will trigger an alert. It's not perfect but its ok for the use case i had.

Comment: I've found [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-app-engine-cron-job-monitoring-bbf5c2ed6ca3) tutorial on how to monitor CronJobs, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as though its a cronjob, that starts standard Kubernetes Jobs, you could query for the job and then check it's start time, and compare that to the current time.

Note: I'm not familiar with stackdriver, so this may not be what you want, but...

E.g. with bash:

```bash
START_TIME=$(kubectl -n=your-namespace get job your-job-name -o json | jq '.status.startTime')
echo $START_TIME
```

You can also get the current status of the job as a JSON blob like this:

`kubectl -n=your-namespace get job your-job-name -o json | jq '.status'`

This would give a result like:

```json
{
  "completionTime": "2019-09-06T17:13:51Z",
  "conditions": [
    {
      "lastProbeTime": "2019-09-06T17:13:51Z",
      "lastTransitionTime": "2019-09-06T17:13:51Z",
      "status": "True",
      "type": "Complete"
    }
  ],
  "startTime": "2019-09-06T17:13:49Z",
  "succeeded": 1
}
```

You can use a tool like jq in your checking script to look at the **succeeded** or **type** fields to see if the job was successful or not.

So with your START_TIME value you could get the current time or the job completion time (**completionTime**) and if the result is less than your minimum job time threshold you can then trigger your alert - e.g. POST to a slack webhook to send a notification or whatever other alert system you use.